# What is the purpose of the Allocation Callstacks button in Unity's Profile window?

Tags: unity, profiling

I have an idea of what this button does, but I cannot find any specific information in the documentation.

What information does this button add to the profiling data? How can I see this extra information?

[image: Screenshot of Allocation Callstacks button in Unity profiler, in a checked state]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consulting the [Unity documentation on the CPU Profiling tools](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ProfilerCPU.html):

> The recorded memory allocation samples appear in the Profiler window in bright red.
>
> [image: Unity Profiler CPU timeline screenshot showing red boxes for allocations]
>
> ...If the callstack was recorded for the selected allocation sample, the associated callstack symbols are resolved and displayed as well:
>
> [image: Screenshot of the Unity Profiler showing callstack for an allocation]

So: when you have "Allocation Callstacks" enabled, you can click on the red boxes representing managed memory allocations to see what code caused memory to be allocated, and where it was called from.

Answer (score 1):

These call stacks are also visible in Hierarchy view, albeit admittedly a bit more hidden. The Nice thing here is that they can be selected and copied out:
[image]

1. Find the drop-down that reads "no Details" by default and switch to
   "Show Related Objects"
2. Select one of the "N/A" Objects (yes, awkward name*)
3. Find the call stack in the pane underneath that opens once you select an object

(* The name usually would be something like "MainCamera" for e.g. a render sample and clicking one of these while profiling in the Editor highlights the corresponding object in the Hierarchy view, if it is still around.)